# Blocking a Loop Using UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uialertcontroller

is there a way for us to block a for loop?

I have a loop where inside it, it ask user with a dialog box. I would like it to pause the loop after user press OK or Cancel.

Is it possible?

Because looping an alertController looks really ugly especialy when you have many loops.

```
for request in friendRequests
{
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Friend Request", message: "Would you like to accept this friend request?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil);
    let confirmAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil);

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction);
    alertController.addAction(confirmAction);

    //How do we block or wait until user press a button??  
    self.navigationController.presentViewController(alertController);
}
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Recursive Function rather than loop

**Example**

```
var name:[String] = ["abcd","efgh","ijkl","mnop","qrst","uvwx"]
self.friendReuqest(name, index: 0)

func friendReuqest(name:[String],index:Int)
{
    if index < name.count
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: name[index], message: "Would you like to accept this friend request?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel){ (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            // do stuff here when press cancel
        }

        let confirmAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.friendReuqest(name, index: (index + 1))
        }

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating loops, implement a logical method that calls itself after user's decision.

Change method implementation like:

```
func showAlert(var requestIndex : Int)
{
    if (requestIndex < friendRequests.count)
    {
        var request = friendRequests[requestIndex]
        requestIndex++
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Friend Request", message: "Would you like to accept this friend request?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:{ action in
            showAlert(requestIndex)
        });
        let confirmAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in
            showAlert(requestIndex)
        });

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction);
        alertController.addAction(confirmAction);

        //How do we block or wait until user press a button??
        self.navigationController.presentViewController(alertController);
    }
}
```

Initially call the method like:

```
showAlert(0);
```